# JsTree - Get Degree of Node

Tags: javascript, tree, jstree

How can I get the degree of a node in a JsTree. For instance, the root is degree 1, its direct children would be 2 and their direct children would be 3. It would be ideal if I could do something like this `tree.get_node(id).get_degree();`

Any ideas?

Comment: [Similar question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908386/jstree-get-the-level-of-selected-node)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jstree get the level of selected node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908386/jstree-get-the-level-of-selected-node)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

```
var degree = tree.get_path(id).length;
```

Comment: Oh, Ill try that tonight. If it works I'll give you the upvote! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `aria-level` attribute of `li` element like below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/jutztb9a/).

```
$('#'+nodeId).attr('aria-level')
```

, where `nodeId` is the id of the node in question.

Comment: You can accept the other answer. Looks more clean to me.